# How to select each checkbox and get its label of a dynamic dropdown using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

So I have this following HTML:

```
<div data-baseweb="popover" id="bui4" class="fc ap ao gc if ig ih ii ij ik iz g2 j0 j1 io">
   <div class="gc if ig ih ii cj b5">
      <div class="ip iq b6 ag b8">
         <div class="ag b8 hu ae">
            <div class="j5 ag am ai">
               <button data-baseweb="button" class="bm bn ai bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by b1 bz c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ca ax ay az b0 ig ih if ii cf cg ch ci cj it j6 iv j7">
                  <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" color="#000000">
                     <title>Arrow left</title>
                     <path d="M22 13.5H6.3l5.5 7.5H8.3l-6.5-9 6.5-9h3.5l-5.5 7.5H22v3z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                  </svg>
               </button>
               <div class="ax ay az b0">Stores</div>
               <div class="j2 j3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag b8 f3 f5">
               <div data-baseweb="input" class="ar ag cn af ft fu fv fw fx fy fz g0 g1 c1 g2 if ii ig ih ax h6 g3 h7 g5 g6 g7 g8 gc gh g9 j8">
                  <div class="ag ai bo gn c1 g2 ax h6 g3 h7 j9 is cj gc">
                     <svg data-baseweb="icon" title="Search" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="ja jb jc jd je">
                        <title>Search</title>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11 6C8.79086 6 7 7.79086 7 10C7 12.2091 8.79086 14 11 14C13.2091 14 15 12.2091 15 10C15 7.79086 13.2091 6 11 6ZM5 10C5 6.68629 7.68629 4 11 4C14.3137 4 17 6.68629 17 10C17 11.2958 16.5892 12.4957 15.8907 13.4765L19.7071 17.2929C20.0976 17.6834 20.0976 18.3166 19.7071 18.7071C19.3166 19.0976 18.6834 19.0976 18.2929 18.7071L14.4765 14.8907C13.4957 15.5892 12.2958 16 11 16C7.68629 16 5 13.3137 5 10Z"></path>
                     </svg>
                  </div>
                  <div data-baseweb="base-input" class="ag af gb c1 g2 ax h6 g3 h7 cj gc"><input aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" autocomplete="on" inputmode="text" name="" placeholder="Search" type="text" class="ar it bp br bq bs bt bv bu bw bx af gd ge gf be jf jg gh g9 ax ay g3 g4 cj gi gj" value=""></div>
               </div>
               <div class="ag cu"><button data-baseweb="button" class="bm bn ai bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by b1 bz c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ca ax ay az b0 cb cc cd ce cf cg ch ci fq ck cl cm jh">Select all</button><button data-baseweb="button" disabled="" class="bm bn ai bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by b1 bz c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ca ax ay az b0 cb cc cd ce cf cg ch ci jh">Clear</button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ae j4 hi" style="position: relative;">
               <div style="overflow: visible; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
                  <div aria-label="grid" aria-readonly="true" class="ReactVirtualized__Grid ReactVirtualized__List" role="grid" tabindex="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; direction: ltr; height: 172px; position: relative; width: 375px; will-change: transform; overflow: auto; outline: none;">
                     <div class="ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer" role="rowgroup" style="width: auto; height: 33616px; max-width: 375px; max-height: 33616px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <div style="height: 44px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100%;">
                           <label data-baseweb="checkbox" class="bn ag ai c3 jj f3">
                              <span class="jk c1 g2 jl j2 j3 jm jn ar fx fy fz g0 jo jp jq jr js jt ju jv if ig ih ii bx ja jw ah jx jy jz k0 k1 hl k2"></span><input aria-checked="false" type="checkbox" class="im k3 k4 cn be bf fc" value="">
                              <div class="jw is cj ax h6 az h7 af k5 ag am ai k6 k7 k8">
                                 <div>
                                    <div class="ax ay az b0 co cq cn ji">Store 0</div>
                                    <div class="ax ay g3 g4 h8 co cq cn ji">Sample Address</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height: 44px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 44px; width: 100%;">
                           <label data-baseweb="checkbox" class="bn ag ai c3 jj f3">
                              <span class="jk c1 g2 jl j2 j3 jm jn ar fx fy fz g0 jo jp jq jr js jt ju jv if ig ih ii bx ja jw ah jx jy jz k0 k1 hl k2"></span><input aria-checked="false" type="checkbox" class="im k3 k4 cn be bf fc" value="">
                              <div class="jw is cj ax h6 az h7 af k5 ag am ai k6 k7 k8">
                                 <div>
                                    <div class="ax ay az b0 co cq cn ji">Store 1</div>
                                    <div class="ax ay g3 g4 h8 co cq cn ji">Sample Address</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height: 44px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 88px; width: 100%;">
                           <label data-baseweb="checkbox" class="bn ag ai c3 jj f3">
                              <span class="jk c1 g2 jl j2 j3 jm jn ar fx fy fz g0 jo jp jq jr js jt ju jv if ig ih ii bx ja jw ah jx jy jz k0 k1 hl k2"></span><input aria-checked="false" type="checkbox" class="im k3 k4 cn be bf fc" value="">
                              <div class="jw is cj ax h6 az h7 af k5 ag am ai k6 k7 k8">
                                 <div>
                                    <div class="ax ay az b0 co cq cn ji">Store 2</div>
                                    <div class="ax ay g3 g4 h8 co cq cn ji">Sample Address</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height: 44px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 132px; width: 100%;">
                           <label data-baseweb="checkbox" class="bn ag ai c3 jj f3">
                              <span class="jk c1 g2 jl j2 j3 jm jn ar fx fy fz g0 jo jp jq jr js jt ju jv if ig ih ii bx ja jw ah jx jy jz k0 k1 hl k2"></span><input aria-checked="false" type="checkbox" class="im k3 k4 cn be bf fc" value="">
                              <div class="jw is cj ax h6 az h7 af k5 ag am ai k6 k7 k8">
                                 <div>
                                    <div class="ax ay az b0 co cq cn ji">Store 3</div>
                                    <div class="ax ay g3 g4 h8 co cq cn ji">Sample Address</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height: 44px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 176px; width: 100%;">
                           <label data-baseweb="checkbox" class="bn ag ai c3 jj f3">
                              <span class="jk c1 g2 jl j2 j3 jm jn ar fx fy fz g0 jo jp jq jr js jt ju jv if ig ih ii bx ja jw ah jx jy jz k0 k1 hl k2"></span><input aria-checked="false" type="checkbox" class="im k3 k4 cn be bf fc" value="">
                              <div class="jw is cj ax h6 az h7 af k5 ag am ai k6 k7 k8">
                                 <div>
                                    <div class="ax ay az b0 co cq cn ji">Store 4</div>
                                    <div class="ax ay g3 g4 h8 co cq cn ji">Sample Address</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </label>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="resize-triggers">
                  <div class="expand-trigger">
                     <div style="width: 376px; height: 173px;"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="contract-trigger"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="ic"><button data-baseweb="button" disabled="" class="bm bn ai bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by b1 bz c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ca ax ay az b0 ig ih if ii cf cg ch ci af">Apply</button></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: dropdown]

This is a dynamic dropdown, so if I will scroll down more, `div` under `ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer` will show more.

This will be the step that I need:

1: Open dropdown, select first checkbox, get store name and address, click APPLY button...

2: Open dropdown, select second checkbox, get store name and address, click APPLY button...

3: Open dropdown, select third checkbox, get store name and address, click APPLY button...

.

.

.

Last n: Open dropdown, select nth checkbox, get store name and address, click APPLY button...

But by following the step, the dynamic scroll inside the dropdown must be considered.

Also, I just want to mention, when hitting the page source of the page, I cannot see the HTML above. I can only see it when opening the dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution i use is to create a path that point's on every result we can have

```
//div[@class="ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer"]/div
```

This will show me how ever many result i might have

then i will get it's size in my code and finaly create a loop on the size i got so that it checks every one of them of course you can get the data you need by adding

```
//div[@class="ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer"]/div[i]
```

i hope it works for you !